# hodge stars of 2-forms in 4-space

Tags: vector-analysis

I have a question regarding the calculation of hodge stars of $2$-forms in $4$-space. I am having trouble understanding the six expressions, such as $*(dx\wedge dy) = dz\wedge dt$ and $*(dz\wedge dx) = -dy\wedge dt$. I am simply confused on how to apply to definition. The six expressions and the definition can be found on this webpage:

http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/minkowski-space/

Comment: I have TeXified the math-syntax parts of your question, as indicated in the [Markdown editing help](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).